# Attempt to index field 'wikibase' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, mediawiki

I have imported to my **MediaWiki** site the *it.Wikipedia* [Modulo:Bio](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo:Bio) but I get this error:

```
Error Lua in Module:Bio line 700: attempt to index field 'wikibase' (a nil value).
```

In line 700 I have this code:

```
local entity = mw.wikibase.getEntityObject()
```

I have multiple wikis that shares the same source code, and the same database, but with its own tables. Then my wikibase is `mybase.mywiki.com`.

I tried to solve by changing `wikibase` to `mybase`:

```
local entity = mw.mybase.getEntityObject()
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `wikibase`: the error simply says that there is no field named `wikibase` in the `mw` table, so the problem is that `mw` doesn't contain what you think it should. You must find the code that puts `wikibase` field in `mw`. If it does something like `mw.wikibase = something` and `something` is nil, then it is as if that line had not executed (it is not an error to assign nil to a table field, it is like removing the field if it exists already, and doing nothing if it doesn't exist). This is common error when `something` is an function call, the function may return nil under some circumstances.